# How to guard against nulls in python

Tags: python

In python, how do I check if a string is either null or empty?

In c# we have `String.IsNullOrEmpty(some_string)`

Also, I'm doing some regex like:

```
p = re.compile(...)

a = p.search(..).group(1)
```

This will break if group doesn't have something at index 1, how do guard against this ? i.e. how would you re-write those 2 lines safely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check for it. Explicit is better than implicit, and one more line won't kill you.

```
a = p.search(...)
if a is not None:
    # ...
```

Comment: Python usually favors EAFP to LBYL style, and this is going to be slower than `try/except` if `a` is usually not `None`.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: slow? how slow would checking None compared to executing the regex? Your first priority should be to write a correct and readable code, not fast and wrong code.

Comment: @Tim: premature optimisation and all that (and I don't think it'd be significant, compared to the regex runtime). I find it clearer (because `re.search` returning `None` is a documented behaviour) than checking for `AttributeError` (which also might e.g. hide a typo).

Comment: @Lie: Have you `timeit()` ed it?  `if` statements are quite measurably slower than `try/except` unless the exception triggers. Probably doesn't matter much in this case, though. My solution isn't any more or less wrong than this, it follows the exact same logic. I agree that catching `AttributeError` is not as obvious to some who don't know the `re` module that well, which is an argument for doing it Piotr's way. I still prefer the `try/except` version, but it seems I'm in the minority here :)

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Searching a typical small regex expression `r'(http|ftp)://([^@]+)@([^\/]+)'` in a small string that always matches: `p.search("http://some@www.example.com")`, the version using `if` measures 2.8451691599999549 seconds and the version using `try` measures 2.8336125200000311 seconds. Ok, you're correct, thanks for saving 0.01 second of my life.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: the re module states that .search() returns None when no strings are found; however, nothing in Python documentation says that accessing None.group will cause AttributeError. At best, the documentation do state that accessing non-existent attribute will throw AttributeError, and it probably says that C-objects (e.g. None) cannot have dynamic attributes and does not originally have .group() attribute, and it probably also says that None is one of those special C-objects. All that, while I can be sure that None-check will always work.

Comment: Is now a bad time to point out, simplicity is better. Doing a simple if seems more simplistic than a full try/except.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Just think how many millions of wasted CPU cycles make up those 0.01 seconds! :) Alright, you have convinced me that this is a case where the `if` construct is much better. Thanks for not giving up on me.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way with re module is:

```
m = p.search(..)
if m: 
    a = m.group(1)
```

or

```
m = p.search(..)
a = m.group(1) if m else ''
```

Unfortunately (or fortunately), Python does not allow you to write everything in one line.

Comment: but group may not having anything at index 1 no?

Comment: @Blankman: if `.group(1)` does not match anything, then either m should be None or calling `m.group(1)` returns an empty string -- depending on how you write your regex. You can check for empty string if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

p.search(..) will return **None**, if nothing was found, so you can do:

```
a = p.search(..)
if a is None:
    # oops
    print "Nothing found"
else:
    print "Hooray!"
```

Answer (score 0):

By "null or empty" I suppose you mean `None` or `""`.  Luckily, in python both of these evaluate to `False`.

If your C# looks like this:

```
if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(some_string))
    do_something();
```

Then your Python would look like this:

```
if not some_string:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score -2):

This might be incorrect but I think you can use if p != None (or it might be null/NULL)

Comment: `p` is not going to be `None`, but `p.search("foo")` might be.

Comment: Also, `is` should be used for singletons (i.e. `None`).